# Trying to print a star triangle in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
section .data
        star db '*'
        num db '1'
        endl db 10
        line db '1'
    section .text
     global _start

    _start:

    Star:
        mov edx,1           ;using 1 byte as appropriate
        mov ecx,star        ;;moving num into ecx to print the star
        mov ebx,1           ;;_STDOUT
        mov eax,4           ;;SYS_WRITE
        int 80h

         inc byte [num];num= 2

        mov al, [line];al=1
        mov bl, [num];bl=1
        cmp al,bl
        je Star;always false



        jmp PrintLine
      ;loop

    PrintLine:

        mov edx,1;using 1 byte as appropriate
        mov ecx,endl ;;moving num into ecx to print the star
        mov ebx,1  ;;_STDOUT
        mov eax,4  ;;SYS_WRITE
        int 80h

        inc byte [line] ;2
        cmp byte[line] , '9' ;comparing 2 to 9

        jl Star

    end:
    mov eax,1 ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0 ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

the result for this code is just single stars in 9 rows but i cannot figure how to increment number of stars as the number row increases. PLEASE HELP. I used Two loops where one loops is inside the other. And increment if a jump fails or passes. One loop is used to print stars and other is supposedly used to print the next line. I have written out the logic a bunch of times and logically it seems to work but i cant figure out the syntax and the placement of the code

Comment: You don't need memory for your loop vars, you still have ESI, EDI and EBP.  That would probably be easier to debug while you single-step your code in the debugger.  Or more efficiently (and maybe more simply), append a star + newline to a buffer and increment `length` in EDX to write more bytes per system call.

Answer (score 1):

I like to break each part in to steps. To begin with, I wouldn't use memory for the variables. As Peter points out, there's `esi` and `edi` still available.

```
_start:

    mov esi, 0 ; line counter
    mov edi, 0 ; star counter
```

The main loops task is basically to check if we've reached 9 lines and exit if so. If not though, we need to print some stars:

```
main_loop:

    inc esi
    cmp esi, 9
    jg end ; have we hit 9 lines?

    ; print 1 whole line of stars
    call print_line

    jmp main_loop
```

Now we need to actually print a line of stars:

```
print_line:

    mov edi, 0; we've printed no stars yet, this is a new line

printline_loop:

    call print_star ; print a single star character
    inc edi ; increment the number of stars we've printed
    ; have we printed the same number of stars as we have lines?
    cmp edi, esi
    jne printline_loop
    call print_eol

    ret
```

To finish up, the final set of individual subroutines to print a star or a newline character:

```
print_star:

    mov edx, 1
    mov ecx, star
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h

    ret

print_eol:

    mov edx, 1
    mov ecx, endl
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h

    ret

end:

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

[Here it is running at IDEOne](https://ideone.com/FFiQ3p)

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

Comment: No problem @BevatronRadar - I hope you stuck with this (as it appears to have been asked over a month ago) and managed to figure it out.